# javascript syntax error "unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I have an issue with my `react` app. 
It forbids me to use common `JavaScript` syntax. An error will be thrown. I don't know where to start to fix the problem. If there is still some information missing, please leave a comment. Then I will add the missing information. Sorry, if the contribution should be too broad.

The situation:

I have implemented `react` (version 16.8) in my `laravel` application (version 5.7). Maybe there comes the error from and something is not correct or missing.

When I'm trying to use this kind of code in one of my components (which seems to be valid to me)

```
checkForUpdatingFreights = async () => {
...
}
```

I get the error

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token (51:29)
>
> ...
>   checkForUpdatingFreights = async () => {
>
> ```
>                            ^
> ```
>
> axios.get('../data/get/json/freightsCurrentlyUpdating')
>   .then((response) => {...

If I rewrite the code this way, it works:

```
checkForUpdatingFreights() {
...
}
```

Does anyone of you have a hint, why the syntax is not being accepted?
Here is the complete code of the `react` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import axios from 'axios';

const RefreshLink = styled.a`
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
`

const signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

class UpdatingFreightsInfo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            freightsInUpdateProcess: false,
            hasFreightsBeenInUpdateStatusSincePageLoad: false,
            intervalId: -1,
        };

        this.checkForUpdatingFreights = this.checkForUpdatingFreights.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUpdatingFreightsInfo();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    getUpdatingFreightsInfo() {
        let intervalId  = setInterval(() => {
            this.checkForUpdatingFreights();
        },30000);
        this.setState({
            intervalId: intervalId
        });
    }   

    checkForUpdatingFreights = async () => {
        axios
        .get('../data/get/json/freightsCurrentlyUpdating')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if(response != undefined && response != null) {
                if(response.data.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        freightsInUpdateProcess: true,
                        hasFreightsBeenInUpdateStatusSincePageLoad: true,
                    });
                }
                else {
                    this.setState({
                        freightsInUpdateProcess: false,
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
    return (
            (this.state.freightsInUpdateProcess || (this.state.hasFreightsBeenInUpdateStatusSincePageLoad && !this.state.freightsInUpdateProcess )) && 
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div className="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
                            <h4 className="alert-heading">Note</h4>
                            {
                                this.state.freightsInUpdateProcess && 
                                <p className="mb-0">Some freight entries are currently being updated.</p>
                            }
                            {
                                this.state.hasFreightsBeenInUpdateStatusSincePageLoad && !this.state.freightsInUpdateProcess && 
                                <p className="mb-0">
                                    The update process has been finished.
                                    <br />
                                    <span className="fa fa-refresh"></span><a href="/" target="_self">Please refresh the page</a>
                                </p>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UpdatingFreightsInfo;
```

Comment: async belongs to es2017 and may be ur compiler doesnt recognise it and recognises previous versions only. Did you check your babel version

Comment: Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6. You'll need to transpile your code (e.g. using Babel) to a version of JS that Node understands if you are using an older version.

Comment: Thanks. That was the hint. I need to upgrade laravel-mix to a current version. Thanks for your help!